# How do I position things like audio controls and submit text inputs?

Tags: javascript, css, html, audio, submit

```
<p>Choose Your Attack</p>
<form action="javascript:ale()">
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="find">
        <input type="submit">
    </div>
</form>
<span></span>

<audio controls>
  <source src="k_01.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="k_01.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">

</audio>
```

Above In my code are the two things I want to position (with full control (unlike using br and centre)(probably by choosing the pixel position)) I don't know how to move them and want them to fit inside a bordered box. How would I position these two things?

Comment: With inline positioning: style="position:relative;top:12px;left:13px;" is possible.

Comment: sorry so where exactly should I put that?

Comment: <audio style="position:relative;top:12px;left:13px;" controls> Of course you should add your bordered box which is not seen in your html.

Comment: The better practice to take your css to external file or to head of the page.